# “against” meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions

> Containment Certification Scheme (CCS) to support the certification of facilities **against** the WHO Global Action Plan to minimize poliovirus facility-associated risk after type-specific eradication of wild polioviruses and sequential cessation of oral polio vaccine use (GAPIII, Annex 2 and Annex 3)

Could you please help me with **against**’s meaning in this sentence?
This is from [GAPIII Containment Certification Scheme](http://polioeradication.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/CCS.pdf) by WHO.
I thought against meant *in opposition with*, but since this paper is from WHO, it does not make sense. The scheme cannot be contrary to the WHO’s action plan. Please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an unusual use of "against" that is documented in the OED:

> Towards, with respect to, in regard to. Obs.

The paragraph is saying "...support the certification of facilities *with respect to* the WHO Global Action Plan..."